# Python - tqdm nested loops spanning multiple scripts

Tags: python, tqdm

As the description mentions I have two scripts that works in the following way:

1. Script1.py have one nested loop i.e two loops both with tqdm decorator attached to them
2. Script2.py is a multiprocess script which calls a list and function from script1.py to be processed
   in the pool.map function.This script does nothing new other than adding multiprocessing.

I created these scripts in this way for them to be modular. When script1.py is called by itself there will be two progressbars in the output **loop1** and **loop2** which works very well. However, when script2.py is called the thought is that I want the same here but with the tweak that **loop1** from script1.py is replaced by **loop1** in the multiprocessing function in script2 (they should be equivalent).

Now, it kind of works half way. What is happening is that both progressbars share the same space/line in the commandline output. So at this point I have to choose between loop1 and loop2 if I want to use multiprocessing. Actually both can be ON but loop1 will just occasionally flash by. Sorry for not presenting code since it would be way convoluted. I have consulted the tqdm documentation many times but can't get my head around it. I tried the `position` option but that just makes the progressbars jump allover the place despite the loops having `leave=false`. Not sure if I made it worse for myself by both doing it modular and multiprocessing. I could just move the content of script2.py to script1.py and be done with it but I'm evaluating parallelization for my projects. 
Is there a way to make both progressbars "aware" of each other so they stop using each others space? Not seen anyone else having this kind of problem maybe I'm doing in an odd way?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this will solve your problem, but it may help understand the `position` problem:

```
from tqdm import trange
from time import sleep
lv = False
num0, num1 = 0, 1
for i in trange(2, desc='loop0', position = num0):
    for j in trange(4, desc='loop1', leave=lv, position=num1):
            #print(j);  #num1 -= 1
            for k in trange(100, desc='loop2', leave=lv, position=2):
                    #num+=1
                    sleep(0.01)
```

If you are running your scripts through a notebook, it does jump all over. Probably because it won't support changing cursor position. The scripts worked like [this image in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCcXW.png).

[Update](https://towardsdatascience.com/learning-to-use-progress-bars-in-python-2dc436de81e5): `alive_progress` seems not to present much problem, you can try that too

```
from alive_progress import alive_bar
import time
with alive_bar(9) as bar:
     for i in range(9):
         bar()
         time.sleep(0.01)
         with alive_bar(9) as bar2:
             for j in range(9):
                 bar2()
                 print(j)
```

Comment: Thank Himanshu Tanwar for your response!
To clarify I'm on win10 and I run the script form the cmd. 
The answer is no it doesn't get close to solving my problem. Additionally I have some commens on your script. Feel free to correct me. The `lv=True` is making the code jump all over the place and should be set to `lv=false`. The `num+=1` is an interesting flavour of adding tqdm but doesn't really represent how the loops are running properly. The `position` should be set directly with integers representing the outputline in cmd for the code to work well. Not tried you code in MP though.

Comment: After your comment I ran some more tests. These are what I noted:

1. Each time a progress bar completes at its position, it gets removed in Terminal if you `set leave False`. Else if you keep `True`, new progress bars add for each loop and previous one's (upper loops - at `position 0`) are lost, but they come back later when they get altered. That's why `lv=True` did work in my previous code because of `num+=1` thing.

2. If you print something in between, the position of already running progress bar is lost no matter what. That's what multiproc will be doing I expect.

Comment: [This link](https://medium.com/better-programming/python-progress-bars-with-tqdm-by-example-ce98dbbc9697) has some pooling examples, you may want to refer them.
Also I'm sure now that `position` will definitely be able to solve thee problem.

Comment: Thanks for putting time into looking into my problem! I just want to clarify the problem. The examples are not necessary bad but using multiple scripts and tqdm making the progressbar "aware" of each other across the scripts seems to be a problem. Maybe I'm missing out a python principle? By themselves the scripts works good with tqdm but if one loop is in one script and the other in another scripts (connected/nested) they seems cancel each other out using the same line and when I try various `leave=True` combinations it starts to jump allover the place. BTW thanks for the link!